# Excel Vba – how verify html child element is there or not

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am making excel file to get product price from site and compare. So far i managed to parse product name and price. but problem comes when product is on sale, then it had different element as shown below 1 is normal 2 is on sale
1.

```
<div class="price">
   <span>$87</span>
</div>
```

2

```
<div class="price">
   <del>100</del>
   <ins>80</ins>
</div>
```

I am doning

```
Set hPrice = hPord(r).getElementsByClassName("price")  
for loop    
ActiveSheet.Range("H6").Offset(r, 0).Value = hPrice(0).innerText
```

this work fine for normal product price but on sale product it returns "100 80"
i try to use

```
If Not hPrice(0).getElementsByTagName("ins") Then
```

this gives error when "ins" is not present,
pleae let me know how to verify child tag is there or not, or you have better alternative

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add index of `<ins>` tag to your line. This could be something like this:

```
 If Not hPrice(0).getElementsByTagName("ins")(0) Then
```

in other words, to get the product price value you need to have this line:

```
hPrice(0).getElementsByTagName("ins")(0).innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below samples

`If Not hPrice.getElementsByTagName("ins")(0) Then`

OR

`If Not hPrice.getElementsByTagName("ins") Then`